# Jasper Reports and Go API

Tags: go, jasper-reports

is there a way to generate reports from a .jrxml file into .pdf / .xlsx / .csv using Go API? I need to convert a Java Spring API into Go API for a project I'm working on. I tried asking ChatGPT, but most libraries does not work. I tried creating one but it didn't work, it only generate hard coded reports.